# I can't play a sound when get a new push notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently using Firebase Cloud Messaging JS API for this purpose, and everything is working very well. However, I'm trying to play a notification sound when a new notification arrives.

I'm aware that I can't play a sound directly from JavaScript due to autoplay restrictions. I tried a small hack by requesting permission to access the microphone to trigger the automatic sound playback permission, but I'm not satisfied with the final result.

I see that applications like Slack, WhatsApp, and others are able to play a sound after requesting notification permissions. Do you have any ideas on the best way to achieve this goal?

I'm leaving the fragment where I perform my 'trick' to request permission to the microphone and thus activate automatic sound playback.

```
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            // Solicitar permiso para acceder al audio
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    // El usuario ha otorgado permisos para acceder al audio
                    console.log('Permisos de reproducción de audio concedidos')

                    // Reproducir el sonido automáticamente
                    const audioElement = new Audio(`${mediaPath}/sounds/level-up-191997.mp3`)

                    audioElement.play();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // El usuario ha denegado el permiso para acceder al audio
                    console.error('Permisos de reproducción de audio denegados:', error)
                });
        } else {
            console.error('getUserMedia no está disponible en este navegador')
        }
```